# Quando usar ícone, ou texto, ou ícone mais texto?

Tags: ux

É comum vermos, em softwares para qualquer plataforma, alguns lugares onde o usuário pode selecionar uma opção e para identificar lá o que é esta opção pode haver um ícone, ou pode haver um texto curto, ou ainda podemos encontrar ambos.

Imagino que existam contextos onde uma opção é mais adequada que outra. Ou será que só uma delas é adequada e as outras são usadas erroneamente?

Por contexto, falo da plataforma, do tipo de aplicação, do tipo de operação onde tem esta representação, tipo de audiência, etc.

Alguns softwares adotam um *default* mas deixam escolher isto. Existe alguma desvantagem em dar esta escolha para o usuário?

Obviamente não estou buscando opiniões, nem quero saber o que você usa. Preciso de justificativa clara e tão fundamentada quanto possível.

Eu sei que idealmente testes devem ser feitos com a audiência. Nem sempre isto é possível, por um motivo ou outro.

Comment: [Aqui](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1795/when-to-use-icons-vs-icons-with-text-vs-just-text-links) tem uma discussão bem parecida, em inglês :(

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Comment: Rapaz, caprichou dessa vez heim? :)

Comment: @LuizVieira só para fazer a resposta ser mais caprichada ainda. Já falei que as suas respostas são sempre as melhores? Já! Mas não custo repetir :)

Comment: Poxa, essa foi realmente difícil de responder sem ser muito prolixo.

Comment: Não vi essa parte então :P

Comment: Quando tem um icone use **sempre** texto. Pelo menos no tooltip (quando passa o rato por cima do icone).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Eis uma pergunta bem difícil (mas, sabe como é, *challenge accepted*!). :)

Inevitavelmente eu preciso começar com um pouco de teoria.

### Semiótica

A disciplina que trata do significado de imagens e textos se chama [Semiótica](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi%C3%B3tica). Ela é amplamente estudada pelas Ciências Humanas (particularmente Letras, Comunicação e Filosofia) porque tem uma forte relação com a forma como nós humanos damos significado a essas "coisas" do mundo. Eu não vou entrar em muitos detalhes porque o espaço aqui é curto, o assunto é denso, e também porque eu estou longe de ser um amplo conhecedor. Mas as referências dadas devem ser suficientes pra quem desejar iniciar um aprofundamento.

Essas tais coisas do mundo são chamadas de Signos (ou Sinais, do original em inglês *Signs*). Signos podem ser qualquer coisa que chega à percepção humana, mas cujo significado está apenas dentro da nossa mente:

> Signos tomam a forma de palavras, imagens, sons, odores, sabores,
>   atos ou objetos, mas tais coisas não têm significado intrínseco e se
>   tornam signos apenas quando nós as investimos com significado. 'Nada
>   é um signo a não ser que seja interpretado como um signo.'
>   ([Charles S. Peirce](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Sanders_Peirce) 1931-58).

<sup>Tradução livre do original em: [Daniel Chandler, Semiotics for Beginners](http://visual-memory.co.uk/daniel/Documents/S4B/sem02.html)</sup>

Quando se diz que um signo só é um signo quando é imbuído de significado, isso quer dizer basicamente que na natureza (isto é, ai pelo mundo), textos, imagens, sons, odores e etc são apenas elementos físicos ou abstratos que só ganham algum significado quando alguém vai lá e não apenas os percebe mas também os representa mentalmente e interpreta em algum contexto. Assim, o signo é formado por uma relação entre três partes (segundo Pierce):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- ***Representamen***. É a forma como o signo se apresenta, seja ele uma imagem, um texto, um odor, um som, etc. É aquilo que chega diretamente aos sentidos humanos, ou seja, a parte perceptível do signo. Por exemplo, é um desenho de um carro.
- **Objeto**. É a coisa propriamente dita, ou seja, a que o signo se refere. Pode ser um objeto físico, como o carro que foi usado como base para o desenho, mas também pode ser algo abstrato desde que seja um conceito "disponível no mundo real", como um carro não-tripulado de origem alienígena.
- **Interpretante**. É aquilo que é criado na mente de quem percebe o signo. Por exemplo, a imagem mental da lembrança de seu próprio carro. Naturalmente, o interpretante é individual e intimamente pessoal, pois advém não somente da qualidade do *representamen* em passar atributos do objeto, mas também das experiências passadas do indivíduo que tem contato com o signo. Por isso a linha entre *representamen* e interpretante no diagrama acima é pontilhada, para indicar que essa relação não é necessariamente direta ou observável.

Peirce, que [foi um dos pais da Semiótica](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce-semiotics/), descreveu também que os signos se dividem em três categorias fundamentais quando a tríade anteriormente descrita é pensada com foco no objeto. São elas:

- **Ícone**. Um ícone é aquele que tem *alguma semelhança* com o objeto e por isso nos faz lembrar dele. Um exemplo é a relação entre a cor vermelha e o sangue e o som de grito e a dor. No caso de imagens, ele pode ser ilustrativo, como fotografias ou desenhos de pessoas, ou diagramático, como placas de "pare" com uma mão aberta em riste ou "proibido fumar" com um cigarro partido. A figura a seguir é um ícone de um rosto humano:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Índice**. Um índice contém uma *relação direta* com o objeto, mostrando algo que aconteceu ou vai acontecer com ele. Ou seja, são representações de *indícios* de algo. Exemplos são pegadas na areia e o cheiro de gás vazando. Em imagens podem ser desenhos de fumaça para indicar calor ou de traços para indicar movimento. A maioria das placas de sinalização de trânsito são índices porque representam informação que se relaciona com uma ocorrência sobre o objeto. Por exemplo, a placa de "superfície escorregadia" a seguir representa a possibilidade de perder o controle do carro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Símbolo**. O símbolo possui uma *relação convencionada* com o objeto, aceita coletivamente por uma comunidade, e criada normalmente de forma arbitrária já que não tem necessariamente uma relação significativa como as duas anteriores. Um exemplo óbvio são as próprias palavras, que são convencionadas em cada idioma (os grupos) para representar os objetos ("carro", "car", "voiture", etc, representam um carro). Um exemplo muito bom que é mais próximo de nós programadores é o desenho de uma casa usado em botões. Ele é tanto um ícone, no sentido de que lembra uma casa, como um símbolo, no sentido de que foi convencionado para significar a ação de ir para a página principal (*home*):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>As fontes das imagens e dos exemplos são o artigo [Icons, Symbols and a Semiotic Web](http://markboulton.co.uk/journal/icons-symbols-and-a-semiotic-web), e o vídeo [O que é Semiótica?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEbGr0nluHQ).</sup>

### Gestalt

Antes de mais nada, como os signos são elementos usados para a comunicação, ao fazer o design não dá pra se pensar em apenas um dos aspectos da tríade *representamen*-objeto-interpretante. É necessário pensar em toda a relação, que permite a interpretação ao signo por parte das pessoas que terão acesso a ele. Uma questão importante é justamente o fato da interpretação ser pessoal e dependente de contexto, o que se chama de [*Gestalt*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt).

Por exemplo, a interpretação da clássica imagem do [Vaso de Rubin](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaso_de_Rubin) como um vaso ou como duas faces humanas depende de *uma escolha*, mental e imediata, a respeito do que é frente e do que é fundo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso é ainda mais notável no quadro "Message d'Amour des Dauphins" (eu desconheço o autor, minha fonte [é essa página](http://sites.psu.edu/liberte/2013/09/13/innocence-and-lust-message-damour-des-dauphins/)), pois nesse caso a interpretação depende também das experiências pessoais passadas. Se você é suficientemente adulto para já ter tido relações sexuais (ou para saber do que se tratam), você sempre enxergará um casal e precisará se esforçar bastante para enxergar os golfinhos. Mas se você é uma criança ainda um tanto inocente, você muito provavelmente não verá o casal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>Se você se esforçou muito e não viu os golfinhos, não se aflija. [Aqui está o *spoiler*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzKaP.png). :)</sub>

O *Gestalt* é importante porque ele faz parte da forma como nós interagimos com o mundo. É usado amplamente no cinema, por exemplo, para causar sustos com formas e sombras de uma forma similar ao susto que você tem com o casaco e o chapéu no cabideiro a noite, voltando do banheiro pro quarto. De fato, todos esses conceitos discutidos até aqui são amplamente utilizados na comunicação, [principalmente na propaganda](http://medialiteracybrasil.net/2011/08/31/aula-5/).

### Enfim, a Semiótica e o *Gestalt* no Design

Responder à sua pergunta é equivalente a discorrer sobre como a semiótica e o *Gestalt* são importantes para o design de interfaces. Esse é também outro assunto vasto, então vou também tentar ser prático. A essência da sua pergunta é sobre o uso de texto *versus* o uso de imagens em interfaces, então esse vai ser o foco, particularmente em dois aspectos: a apresentação de opções de ação e a apresentação de conteúdo. A sua pergunta parece ser mais no foco das opções de ação, mas eu achei interessante incluir também algo sobre a apresentação de conteúdo.

*1. Opções de Ação*

Por opções de ação entende-se os meios pelos quais o usuário atua no sistema. São menus e botões em caixas de ferramentas, por exemplo. Naturalmente, pode-se optar por texto ou por imagens para representar as ações possíveis. Porém, há de se lembrar que texto é formado por palavras, que são necessariamente signos de símbolos (convenções). Além da eventual dificuldade de interpretação inata das especificidades do indivíduo, o uso de símbolos traz algumas dificuldades a mais.

A primeira delas é a respeito do quão amplo é o grupo em que essa convenção está estabelecida. Palavras são convenções de um idioma, e por isso geram dificuldades para usuários de outros grupos (que não falam inglês, por exemplo). Além disso, elas estão muito distantes do ícone, então *por si só* não lembram em nada o objeto de que tratam. Há a necessidade do usuário fazer toda a relação entre o signo e o objeto, e esse esforço cognitivo adicional pode ser cansativo. É por isso, por exemplo, que palavras difíceis ("riste", que eu mesmo usei neste texto, ou "estóico" - procure num dicionário se não entendeu... hehehe) são ruins porque nem todas as pessoas se sentirão confortáveis com o seu uso (e conforto é uma questão de usabilidade importante).

O uso de um índice para dar significado a uma ação parece mais apropriado, especialmente quando ele também é um ícone que lembra o objeto da ação. Considere o desenho de uma pasta aberta, por exemplo. Ele tem uma relação direta com o objeto (a pasta) e por isso é um bom ícone. Além disso, ele tem uma indicação de estado (o fato de estar aberta) que o torna também um bom índice, no sentido de que ele dá indicações da ação que será realizada.

Voltando ao exemplo do botão *home*, ele está mais para um símbolo tal como uma palavra. A ação é fazer com que a tela volte à página inicial, mas não há uma indicação direta dela. Ainda assim, ele tem uma relação direta com uma casa (é um ícone de uma casa), e pode passar o significado de conforto, o que o torna um bom ícone. Além disso, como símbolo ele é uma convenção amplamente aceita, muito mais ampla no contexto de sistemas do que a palavra *home*, por exemplo. Então ainda assim faz muito sentido utilizá-lo ao invés de um texto, simplesmente porque ele é uma convenção mais ampla.

Claro que nem sempre há uma convenção assim tão estabelecida. Nesses casos, o que parece ser o ideal é:

1. construir o elemento de interface a partir de índices que descrevam as possibilidades de ações ("o que vai acontecer se eu clicar")
2. sempre que possível, fazer também com que ele seja icônico dos objetos envolvidos ("envolve uma impressora")
3. se existente, usar convenções estabelecidas ("setas paralelas opostas significa atualização")

Apesar da sugestão de abordagem primordial pelo índice, é curioso notar que certas convenções ainda se mantêm mesmo tendo relação direta com objetos que provavelmente não são conhecidos da maior parte das pessoas. É o caso do botão salvar da discussão citada em comentários pelo @GabrielOshiro, que usa a imagem de um disquete. Esse tipo de mídia está quase extinta (é provável que muitos usuários mais jovens jamais viram um disquete), e ainda assim é amplamente usado para indicar a ação de salvar (mas discutido nos âmbitos [de usabilidade](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3117/save-icon-is-the-floppy-disk-icon-dead) e [de design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/323/new-generation-of-save-icon-that-is-not-a-disk)). Ainda assim, vale a menção de que essa é uma convenção muito bem estabelecida e já aprendida pelos usuários. Para novas ações, em que não há uma convenção assim tão forte, a sugestão de iniciar o design pelo uso de índices ainda parece válida porque tende a facilitar a compreensão no primeiro contato.

Há de se notar também que mesmo que um ícone, índice ou símbolo seja muito bom em transmitir um significado ele pode não atingir todo mundo (porque, como já mencionado inúmeras vezes, o significado é pessoal e há também a questão do *Gestalt*). Por isso, do ponto de vista da usabilidade é interessante fornecer alternativas para os usuários sejam capazes de compreender e aprender seu significado. Até mais do que isso, o usuário precisa se sentir capaz e seguro de executar a ação sem medo de não ter certeza sobre o que ela faz. Assim, talvez mais eficiente do que fornecer uma configuração (em que o usuário pode decidir por exibir também texto) seja fornecer uma ajuda pontual e contextualizada.

O ícone de ajuda de contexto (em que o usuário clica em uma interrogação e em seguida no item de dúvida) e, especialmente, a exibição de uma mensagem de dica (*tooltip*) quando o mouse para sobre um item por um certo tempo (a parada é um sinal natural de dúvida), são escolhas que parecem melhores do que a configuração porque são contextualizadas no momento da dúvida (o usuário não precisa trocar o contexto para outra tela de configuração, e então ter de se lembrar da dúvida que ele tinha naquele momento).

*2. Apresentação de Conteúdo*

A apresentação de conteúdo trata dos meios pelos quais o usuário percebe as respostas às suas ações no sistema, e também o conteúdo que é comunicado. Há uma gama muito maior de signos que podem ser usados além de texto. Imagens são igualmente úteis, principalmente porque tornam o processo de compreensão menos cansativo. Principalmente signos icônicos, que têm uma relação direta com um objeto, ajudam porque diminuiem a carga cognitiva no entendimento de algo. É por isso que as revistas e a Web usam cada vez mais infográficos.

Mas há um balancemanto importante ai, pois a criação de signos de índice visuais complexos também aumenta a carga cognitiva, principalmente quando requer a representação de algo em três dimensões. É por isso que "manuais de instrução" para a montagem de móveis, que usam apenas desenhos esquemáticos com todas as peças, parafusos e porcas, é difícil para muitas pessoas. Nesses casos algum texto é também necessário para evitar confusões típicas do *Gestalt* (esse parafuso é o A2 ou o A4? São tão parecidos!).

Texto, animações e vídeo também são relevantes na apresentação de conteúdo porque nos permitem exercitar mentalmente como a ação com o objeto se desenrola na figura de personagens: outros indivíduos, fictícios ou não, que fazem a ação no nosso lugar. É natural do ser humano aprender por observação, e ver (ou imaginar) alguém fazendo algo ajuda a perceber as nossas capacidades e dificuldades.

Por fim, sons são também importantes, principalmente no feedback das ações. Esse tipo de signo pode ser explorado de uma forma muito profunda especialmente se atuando como índice, principalmente quando envolve a indicação de que algo importante ocorreu ou está para ocorrer. Do ponto de vista de usabilidade, é importante tê-lo justamente para indicar eventos importantes (alertas, por exemplo). Mas seu abuso, com o uso de sons para cada clique em qualquer botão, por exemplo, pode apenas deixar a interação cansativa.

Answer (score 19):

Eu estou fazendo a cadeira de IHM na faculdade nesse semestre e o professor abordou exatamente esse assunto.

O professor explicou que o sistema precisa ser o mais intuitivo e de fácil entendimento possível. Logo, você pode usar tanto o ícone quanto o texto ou até mesmo os dois para o botão/opção/o que seja, mas precisa ter sempre em mente que o usuário não deve precisar pensar para saber para que serve essa opção.

Ele também explicou que o ideal é que seja seguido um padrão, de preferência um padrão universal para que o usuário não precise pensar para saber para que a opção serve.

Por exemplo:

Em blogs é usado, em geral, os botões de navegação entre as páginas com palavras ou as setinhas, e qual é o correto? Depende, o correto é o mais intuitivo para o usuário e com a menor quantidade de conteúdo possível. Logo, os melhores exemplos seriam os botões:

```
|<<| |<| |1| |2| |3| |4| |5| |>| |>>|
```

Ou então:

```
|Anterior| |Próxima|
```

E um exemplo de botões errados seria:

```
|<< Inicio| |< Anterior| |1| |2| |3| |4| |5| |Próxima >| |Fim >>|
```

Ou

```
|<| |>|  // Nesse caso o usuário não poderia ter certeza qual dos dois botões levam para página anterior.
```

-edit-

Você também precisa levar em consideração a que usuários o seu site/programa se destina. Por exemplo, tu não podes colocar botões somente com palavras caso seus usuários possam ser pessoas analfabetas e nem usar somente símbolos em um programa/site onde tem o público alvo pessoas de mais idade, pois elas costumam não entender vários símbolos (por exemplo: existem muitas pessoas de idade que não entendem que uma carta significa e-mail, pois para elas significa carta, envelope ou até mesmo correio).

Comment: "[...] ter sempre em mente que o usuário não deve precisar pensar para saber para que serve essa opção". Falou e disse. :)