# Aplicando conceitos de UX para desenvolvimento mobile

Tags: mobile, ux

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile e pesquisando a sobre a parte de design para mobiles, li bastante o termo `UX`. Pesquisando, descobri a seguinte definição:

> *Jakob Nielsen e Donald Norman resumem a Experiência do Usuário como
>   uma forma de englobar todos os aspectos da interação do usuário final
>   com a empresa, seus serviços e seus produtos, ou seja, ela é
>   responsável por estudar as melhores maneiras de atender as
>   necessidades dos usuários e deixá-los satisfeitos com todo o processo.*

Fonte: [UX](http://www.designculture.com.br/o-que-e-ui-design-e-ux-design/)

Com relação ao desenvolvimento de telas para uma aplicação mobile, devido aos diversos intempéries que envolvem o mundo mobile (como por exemplo, a grande gama de diversidade de resoluções de telas), que fatores que eu devo me atentar para construir algo que atraia e proporcione uma boa experiência de uso para o usuário final? Quais dicas vocês podem me indicar? Lembrando que não sou da área de design, toda ajuda/dica é sempre bem-vinda!

Comment: Eu poderia responder alguma coisa meia-boca, mas não acho que alguém aqui conseguiria responder melhor que o Luiz Vieira.

Comment: Então seria uma o @Luiz Vieira responder, não é mesmo @bigown?!

Comment: A pergunta é boa, mas eu não sei o quão fácil é de responder sem "chover no molhado". A própria [descrição da tag ux](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/ux/info) já tem bastante detalhes sobre a definição. Sobre o uso, bem, as perguntas [que já existem](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ux) sob essa tag também ajudam.

Comment: Duds, dá uma olhada nesse conteúdo que eu indiquei. Se tiver alguma dúvida mais específica, pode editar esta pergunta (ou criar uma nova). Que tal? (e, valeu pelo *summoning*, @bigown :))

Comment: Ok @LuizVieira, estou lendo o conteúdo que vc passou. Pode ser sim, vou reformular minha pergunta.

Comment: Ok, por enquanto eu vou votar pra fechar (só porque ela está redundante com a definição da tag). Creio que vc sabe que isso não significa nada terrível (mesmo fechada, se for alterada é fácil votar pra reabrir). []s P.S.: Uma sugestão de edição é vc focar na questão de ux pra mobile.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque o conteúdo de uma possível resposta tem muita interseção com a definição da tag ux.

Comment: Acabei de editar a pergunta @LuizVieira.

Comment: Ok, retirei o voto (e vou tentar responder). :)

Comment: Obrigado @LuizVieira :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Há algum tempo eu abri uma pergunta semelhante (não acho que é uma duplicata, mas que a comunidade julgue): [Quando e por que criar um aplicativo para dispositivo móvel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73289/quando-e-por-que-criar-um-aplicativo-para-dispositivo-m%C3%B3vel)

No escopo da minha pergunta, eu tinha interesse em entender a motivação para criar uma aplicação móvel. No seu caso, vou considerar que essa motivação já está bem definida.

Do ponto de vista da experiência dos usuários de aplicações móveis, a questão que me parece fundamental é o tamanho do dispositivo. A mobilidade requer que o dispositivo seja suficientemente pequeno e leve, mas as suas dimensões reduzidas dificultam a "tradução" de aplicações como estamos acustumados. Qualquer texto apresentado precisa ser mais curto para poder ter uma fonte maior e assim ser legível enquanto cabe na tela. Por isso, o uso de ícones como [representações de ações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59025/quando-usar-%C3%ADcone-ou-texto-ou-%C3%ADcone-mais-texto) é ainda mais interessante. Quando imagens não são alternativas suficientemente boas, o texto precisa ser apresentado [de forma gradual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56308/muitas-telas-ou-uma-tela-com-muitas-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es) e controlada pelo usuário (fácil paginamento ou rolagem da tela).

A interação também é dificultada pelo tamanho reduzido. Telas de toque são naturalmente intuitivas, mas em interações prolongadas um dedo na tela simplesmente obstrui a fonte de informação (esse é exatamente o caso de jogos, por exemplo, que desenham um joystick na tela para ser controlado pelo dedão). Por isso alternativas como usar comando de voz ou sensores como o acelerômetro podem ser interessantes. Além disso, como a toda a tela (de fato, todo o dispositivo) é sensível ao toque, é importante diferenciar na sua aplicação os elementos visuais (da GUI) que são de fato relacionados com ações daqueles que não são. Botões que "não têm cara de botão" são um problema em qualquer aplicação, mas em um ambiente desktop eles podem ser inferidos como botões pela posição em que estão (central, sempre abaixo, etc) e principalmente pela relação que têm com outros elementos. Nos dispositivos móveis essa relação é mais difícil de ser notada, porque os botões podem ter dimensões muito próximas de outros elementos visuais. Então, para que o usuário entenda como interagir com a aplicação e não se frustre em usá-la, é importante diferenciar bem o que é "tocável" do que não é, e manter um padrão em todas as telas.

Outro caráter importante para a interação móvel é o acesso aos dados. Nem sempre há uma conexão com a Internet disponível, e essa interrupção tende a ser mais comum do que em ambientes não-móveis (em túneis, dentro de shoppings, etc). É terrível para a experiência um usuário não ter acesso a uma informação quando mais precisa. Considere um aplicativo para a aquisição de tickets de cinema, que permita exibir o ticket no celular. O usuário certamente vai tentar utilizar o aplicativo quando estiver para entrar no cinema. Uma falha de comunicação nesse momento pode causar a perda de momentos iniciais do filme, impossibilitando o usuário de entrar no cinema. Ao invés de fazer a aplicação conectar e buscar a informação na hora solicitada, talvez fosse interessante que utilizar serviços do tipo *push* para que o servidor automaticamente enviasse os dados para o dispositivo tão logo possível após a compra. O dispositivo então armazenaria os dados de forma off-line, para garantir a experiência. Note como esse problema não tem uma relação direta com um problema da interface gráfica (GUI), mas sim com a interação de mais alto-nível entre aplicação e usuário e a experiência ("impressão" do usuário) resultante dela.

Adicionalmente, chavear aplicações em dispositivos móveis não é igualmente simples como em aplicações desktop. Essencialmente porque a informação de que há outras aplicações em execução (que no seu Windows ou Ubuntu são abas no topo ou botões na parte inferior) ocupam espaço. Os sistemas operacionais móveis geralmente escondem essa informação, que não é clara para a maioria dos usuários sem o devido treinamento na forma de uso. Assim, é ainda mais importante permitir que o usuário desista de operações longas (vide a minha resposta nesta [outra pergunta aqui do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63561/melhores-pr%C3%A1ticas-ao-apresentar-tela-de-loading-em-android)), e/ou possa continuá-las em outro momento.

Certamente há outras heurísticas que podem ser elencadas, no sentido de serem "melhores práticas conhecidas". Todas são bastante discutíveis e dependentes do domínio da aplicação, até mesmo as que eu coloquei acima (que são as principais, na minha visão, segundo a minha experiência como projetista e também como usuário).

Algo que certamente é um consenso mais geral é que qualquer que seja o seu produto, você deve construir protótipos e avaliar a experiência com a interação com participantes representativos dos seus usuários, além de constantemente coletar feedback dos usuários após a aplicação estar em produção.

Comment: Muito interessante a sua resposta @LuizVieira! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

**UX** é um termo em inglês que significa "User eXperience", e está relacionado à usabilidade e interface gráfica. É um termo mais atualizado para GUI (Graphical User Interface), sendo que a GUI é apenas a "tela", mas a UX é como se fosse uma soma do design da tela com a facilidade e usabilidade da mesma.

Comment: Oi Ulysses. Rapaz, essa passagem é capaz de ofender muitos profissionais: "É um termo mais atualizado para GUI". Talvez (ainda) não aqui no SOPT, mas enfim, fica a dica. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira OK. Se tiver uma explicação melhor, não deixe de compartilhar com a gente.

Comment: Se por acaso você se ofendeu, desculpe (não era a intenção). A sua explicação está boa, o que eu quis dizer é que UX *não é* um termo mais atualizado pra GUI. Só isso achei (bem) errado.

Comment: Também descordo da afirmação citada pelo @LuizVieira