# Ainda faz sentido usar a Metáfora do Desktop?

Tags: ux, acessibilidade, icons, ui, user-interface

<sup>**Sei que perguntas baseadas em UX na maioria das vezes tendem a ser interpretadas como "baseada em opinião", por isso gostaria de respostas com fundamento teórico, seja citando algum artigo ou autor que justifique uma posição sobre o assunto**</sup>

---

Pergunta:

Até hoje é comum vermos o uso da Metáfora do Desktop aplicada como conceito no desenvolvimento de interfaces, um exemplo é o `ícone da lixeira` que é comumente usado em várias interfaces e é representado por uma `lata de lixo`, ou um ícone mais "polêmico", que é o `ícone de Salvar` que normalmente é representado por um `Floppy Disc (Disquete)`, que é um objeto que já não faz parte do nosso dia a dia a muitos anos. Então me parece que o Skeuomorphism no desenvolvimento de interface pode ser uma prática não sustentável a longo prazo...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tendo isso como um ponto, um representação que seja mais intuitiva, com conceitos *affordance* ou talvez com elementos da biomimética seria uma melhor prática para se desenvolver interfaces?

Então devemos abandonar a Metáfora do Desktop / Skeuomorphism e partir para uma interface auto explicativa, *affordance*, e que traga uma representatividade mais atemporal? Talvez até mesmo trocando ícones por texto?

Existe algum outro conceito que podemos aplicar no desenvolvimento dos ícones para as interfaces?

Veja esses ícones, se hoje eles já parecem ser "ultrapassados" e pouco representativos da realidade, será que ainda devemos seguir esse conceito no desenvolvimento da interface?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **OBS:** Gostaria de respostas que tenham pelo menos uma fonte de consulta, ou que sejam fundamentados por algum autor. Não gostaria de respostas baseadas puramente no "achismo".

Comment: Talvez não atemporal, mas mais adaptado ao contexto atual, embora isso poderia gerar outro problema de inconsistência da UI: hoje é um ícone, amanhã é outro.

Comment: Anderson um ponto que tenho receio é justamente esse, mas por outro lado o hamburger Menu  `☰` é um ícone "novo" e que virou quase que padrão, mesmo tendo autores que abominem ele...

Comment: O usuário entendendo, você coloca o ícone que desejar, para mim um disquete é algo que da para entender bem, além de trazer uma nostalgia histórica bem grande. Porém existem outros ícones que podem ser usados como salvar, como um CD por exemplo, um memory card ou qualquer outro ícone, dependendo do contexto que você está usando.

Comment: @FelipeJorge realmente o contexto pode ser algo a ser levado em consideração. Apesar disso eu não "inovaria" de mais... valeu a dica []´s

Comment: Disquete faz sentido pra quem já usou disquete. Pra uma criança de 12 anos de idade nem tanto.

Comment: @Bacco justamente esse foi um ponto de vista que pensei quando falei de "ícone atemporal", no entanto para uma criança de 12 anos o erro faz parte do processo de aprendizado, e mesmo sem ligar a função ao objeto, para ela aquele pictograma vai significar salvar, e ela vai aprender talvez na tentativa e erro, ou por curiosidade clicando "para ver o que acontece", mesmo ela não sabendo o que é um disket. Além disso, já que é um ícone quase que "padrão", na próxima vez que ela ver esse pictograma em outro lugar ela já vai saber do que se trata. O assunto vai longe rss

Comment: Resumindo: cognitivo + cultura = padrão.. Caso você tenha um sistema intuitivo com grande usabilidade, se torna fácil alterar o ícone no seu sistema visto que os utilizadores saberão de fato do que se trata todas as vezes que utilizar.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Não tenho grande fundamentação porque esse tipo de coisa em específico não tem muita teoria fundamentada. UX é muita observação e experiência, usando a base de conhecimento adquirida para tomar decisões. E muitos especialistas em UX que tentam usar regras quebram a cara (alguns dirão que são charlatões) porque UX depende de entendimentos intangíveis. Tentarei na explicação mostrar o que faz sentido, mas dando a chance da pessoa contestar porque tem argumentos.

O que se tem certo na área é que tudo deveria ser feito baseado em experimentos com o público alvo. Eu sei que isso é caro, difícil de realizar e não compensa em muitos casos. Então aí tem que ir no achismo mesmo :) Mas dá para ir no achismo com fundamento (ainda que isso possa ser uma armadilha e te levar pro lugar errado).

Não sei se a questão é de metáfora do desktop.

## Ícones

Sua pergunta responde um pouco o que perguntou. Ela fala de cesta de lixo que é uma metáfora independente da tecnologia usada. A intenção é indicar que ali vai o lixo. Muito raramente alguém que nunca usou um computador vai entender o que se faz ali só porque viu um lixo. O objetivo do ícone não é ensinar os conceitos, é ter uma fonte fácil de você achar e clicar rápido quando quer aquilo (que você já entendeu o conceito). Algumas ações não possuem ícones óbvios e intuitivos.

O objetivo do ícone disquete não é mostrar que vai gravar no disquete, porque faz muito tempo que ele não é usado. O objetivo ali é apenas dizer que vai gravar, não importa se é em HDD, SSD, DVD, nuvem, etc. Hoje é intuitivo para qualquer pessoa que já usou computador que aquilo é gravar. E não é fácil achar outro ícone melhor. Mesmo que ache, trocar pode ser pior, tem que treinar todo mundo de novo com o novo ícone, e pior ainda, a mudança não ocorrerá tudo ao mesmo tempo, o que criará um problema assíncrono pior que mudar.

Já pensou quanta coisa errada no mundo real usamos todos os dias e ninguém arruma porque mudar é um problema grande demais, mesmo que seja para melhor (vide problema das tomadas)? Por que acha que os países não padronizam a direção do carro para a direita ou esquerda? Seria melhor todos os países serem iguais.

Então eu diria que o ícone atemporal é absolutamente secundário agora. Pode ser útil pensar em algo assim para possíveis novos ícones (que nem é tão importante porque saindo dos básicos o ícone ajuda pouco, [o texto passa ser mais importante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59025/101)).

E é a mesma coisa que falo de dar nomes para as coisas, de organizar melhor os objetos. Se você não consegue dar nome correto ou classificar tudo corretamente porque não tem domínio do problema por completo, a mesma coisa vale para achar um ícone atemporal. O que parecia atemporal hoje pode não ser mais no futuro. Não digo que não deva haver alguma preocupação, mas ela é pequena.

Eu acho até que é preocupação em demasia com a usabilidade do ícone. Claro que não pode ter menos preocupação do que merece, tem que pensar um pouco, mas os ícones que importam já estão aí bem definidos e mudar traz mais malefício que benefício.

As imagens da pergunta mostram alguns ícones mais genéricos, porém mais ambíguos também. Não sei o que quer dizer a maioria deles, alguns sem texto eu não teria a menor chance de saber o que é. E estou falando como um programador que mexe com isso há décadas, não como um usuário novato. Mas se eu começar usar uma aplicação com ele, logo eu saberei que é nele que tenho que clicar. Porém se só ele usa assim eu terei que chavear meu conhecimento sempre que for para essa aplicação.

Eu nunca vi alguém reclamando que não sabe o que fazer ou que é pior ter o ícone de um telefone de gancho ou um envelope de carta e não algo menos dependente do meio físico real que está usando. Todo mundo entende. Claro, tem gente que fará piada e reclamará jocosamente, mas não o fará como um problema sério, a não ser que essa pessoa tenha problemas sociais :)

Boa parte do ícones mais conhecidos hoje foram criados há poucos anos e já não se usava muito mais o equipamento original que se usava para aquilo.

O Settings é bem legal. Alguém associa esse ícone com as configurações a não ser depois que aprende que ele é sobre isso? Nem vou entrar no mérito dele não ser muito bem escolhido de forma específica, mal dá para entender que aquilo é uma engrenagem (tem outros aí mesmo que são piores ainda, mas isso é outro problema). E uma engrenagem me remete a máquina industrial, quem sabe moenda de cana-de-açúcar, mas pode ser só pelo meu próprio *bias*.

Outro caso curioso é o Hamburger. Nem vou falar que aquilo é tudo menos um hamburger. Alguém botou um dos ícones mais simples que pode existir, ele não quer dizer nada, não é uma boa metáfora de nada, mas "todo mundo" sabe o que é. Mais um caso que mostra que o ícone não importa.

[image: Seringa]

Não é sobre metáfora, é sobre associação de ideias, a base do processo cognitivo. Você não chama isso de seringa porque há um fato comprovado que é uma seringa, chama assim porque alguém deu esse nome e isso chegou até você, aprendeu assim, e é assim que você chama. E você associou isso com medicina, doença ou cura, dor, hospital, remédio, injeção, etc. Você não associa isso com um plástico circular com um mecanismo de empuxo.

[image: Ícone de Seringa]

Dependendo da cultura pode remeter a outra coisa um pouco diferente, ou o ícone pode ser usado para coisas diferentes.

## Metáfora X idioma

Simplesmente esqueça essa ideia de metáfora. A ideia do **idioma** parece ser muito mais interessante. Faça as pessoas entenderem o que quer passar, e isso sempre é usar o que todos usam.

Uma fonte que possa usar é [pergunta no UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/3117/1490) que já tratou do assunto. Lá tem um bom *link* (na resposta aceita) sobre o mito da metáfora e fundamenta muito do que eu disse. Tem outros *links* (fora os quebrados), e tem a "regra" de *design*:

> Se tudo mais falhar, padronize

Acho que isso diz tudo.

Lá tem opiniões também dizendo como deveria ser o novo ícone de salvar. Não é questão do que "eu" acho melhor, perguntas baseadas em opiniões são aquelas que dizem coisas sem necessidade, que não ajudam, que sejam GTKY, que geram listas de consumo e não argumentam. Argumento não é opinião. O que escrevi aqui faz sentido? Mesmo que esteja errado :P

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Legal Maniero gostei da resposta e da referência (e das referências da referência rss). Acho que a metáfora está entre o limite da representatividade do objeto / função, e o ícone hoje é mais um pictograma, onde o que mais importa é o conceito (função) que está por trás dele do que realmente o objeto que representa. O fato de poder estar ligado a linguagem e bem interessante. Obrigado por contribuir! E o artigo foi publicado no `Visual Basic Programmer's Journal` em 1995 :D

Comment: Acho que foi perfeito, a questão da seringa eu ainda acrescentaria, se ela tiver num sistema de medicina 99% vai saber o que é se clicar ali, se tiver num sistema de recarga de cartucho também vão saber, ou seja, o ícone em si não diz nada, mas quando existe um contexto ele se torna o centro das atenções; estou preenchendo um fomulário e logo abaixo 2 ícones, um V  (de confere como diz meu filho de 4 anos) e um X (que ninguém ouse traduzir :) ) onde vou clicar? O ícones devem ser o máximo intuitivos, mas sem neuroses por favor :)

Comment: @Marcelo exatamente